# Could it be that at the big bang equal amounts of matter and antimatter were created, but the antimatter got stuck in black holes?

Tags: black-holes, big-bang, antimatter, matter, baryogenesis

I recently watched PBS spacetime's video series on the black hole information paradox. Where they first discussed the no hair conjecture and then later also the true destruction of information by Hawking radiation.

This led me to wonder, if information is apparentely unavailable to the outside universe after it has entered a black hole, is it possible that at the big bang equal amounts of matter and antimatter were created, but, by chance, a greater amount of antimatter than matter fell into black holes, leaving slightly more matter than antimatter in the outside universe, most of which anihilated and a small portion makes up everything we can now see?

If this were the case, the black holes of our current universe would contain equally as much antimatter as the rest of the universe contains matter, however, by the no hair conjecture we should not be able detect any difference between a electrically neutral black hole made of matter or antimatter.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer to this question can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188476/could-the-universes-antimatter-be-hiding-in-black-holes?rq=1), although it is not accepted, so maybe there is something wrong with that answer?

I had done some searching before-hand and only found that other question through the related section on my own post, which is why I think I should keep this question here with only this answer so that the answer may be more easily found in the future.

I am simultaneously creating a post on the meta to ask whether this is the prefered course of action or whether I should just delete this question.